# common AND not working with OR in findManyAndCount in typeorm nest js

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am using this typeorm version

> ```
> "typeorm": "^0.3.9",
> ```

I have an entity `SomeEntity` which is linked to `ChildEntity` and `ChildEntity2`

`ChildEntity` has `attrOne` `attrTwo` and `ChildEntity2` has `id` I want apply `OR` `attrOne`, `attrTwo` and `AND` on id

```
const queryOptions: FindManyOptions<SomeEntity> = {
  where: {
    childEntity2: { id: varName.id },
    childEntity: {},
  }
};


conditionOne.childEntity = {
    ...(conditionOne.childEntity as FindOptionsWhere<ChildEntity>),
    attrOne: Raw(
      alias => words.map(word => `LOWER(${alias}) LIKE :search_${word}`).join(' OR '),
      {
        ...words.reduce(
          (params, word) => ({ ...params, [`search_${word}`]: `%${word}%` }),
          {},
        ),
      },
    ),
  };


  conditionTwo.childEntity = {
    ...(conditionTwo.childEntity as FindOptionsWhere<ChildEntity>),
    attrTwo: Raw(
      alias => words.map(word => `LOWER(${alias}) LIKE :search_${word}`).join(' OR '),
      {
        ...words.reduce(
          (params, word) => ({ ...params, [`search_${word}`]: `%${word}%` }),
          {},
        ),
      },
    ),
  };


  const newQueryOption: FindManyOptions<SomeEntity> = { ...queryOptions };
  newQueryOption.where = [
    { ...conditionOne } as FindOptionsWhere<SomeEntity>,
    { ...conditionTwo } as FindOptionsWhere<SomeEntity>,
  ];

  queryOptionsToPass = newQueryOption;



const [data, count] = await this.someRepository.findAndCount(queryOptionsToPass);
```

Issue is result I am getting contains objects that has id other than `varName.id` that i have originally passed

WHY it is so? I want only those objects whose id = `varName.id`

Comment: hint: the value of `where` assigned in `const newQueryOption: FindManyOptions<SomeEntity> = { ...queryOptions };` has being overwritten in the next line.

tip on debugging: for non-production env, you can always enable `logging: true` when importing TypeormModule to show raw sql queries generated. (https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/logging)